# Repitition of entries from database in php script for android

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1B6v.png)

```
$category_id=$_GET["category_id"];
$sql = "SELECT sale_price,product_id,image,name FROM `shop_products` INNER JOIN  `products` ON products.id=shop_products.product_id WHERE products.category_id = '$category_id'";

$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('sale_price'=>$row[0],
'product_id'=>$row[1],
'image'=>$row[2],
'name'=>$row[3]

));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

For fetching the values stated in query from the different tables, i used the above code as a php script for my android application but facing the problem is , each entry is showing repeatedly 2 times.
I ran the query it's not working fine, it is showing me every record two times
i checked out the indexing it is also fine.

Comment: Are there multiple records in `shop_products` for each `product`? (I assume `id` is unique in `products`.)

Comment: yes in products table id is unique and its a primary key and there are multiple records in shop_products but not repeating, when i'm trying to fetch some attributes from these table in a join query only then these are repititive.

Comment: If you join it like that, then you'll get multiple rows for each product, unless you limit it to a specific shop.

Comment: can you please help me in writing a query for this !

Comment: Possibly. Do you want to limit it to a specific shop?

Comment: yes i want to do so

Comment: Just add it to your where clause, then: `and shop_id = ?`